# elixir define dynamic functions inside macro

Tags: elixir

I am trying to define dynamically functions inside `defmacro` but can’t understand why function value is unavailable inside function itself

```
defmacro __using__(_) do
  Enum.each ~w(public private), fn value ->
    def unquote(:"make_#{value}")(user = %User{}) do
       %{user | privacy: value}
    end
  end
end
```

Elixir expands by default `value` to `value()` and then says that there is no such function

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `quote` around the `def`. You also need to unquote the value in the Map update expression inside the `def`. And lastly you need to use `Enum.map` here instead of `Enum.each` so that `__using__/1` returns the AST constructed:

```
defmacro __using__(_) do
  Enum.map ~w(public private), fn value ->
    quote do
      def unquote(:"make_#{value}")(user = %User{}) do
        %{user | privacy: unquote(value)}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```
defmodule User do
  defstruct [:privacy]
end

defmodule A do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    Enum.map ~w(public private), fn value ->
      quote do
        def unquote(:"make_#{value}")(user = %User{}) do
          %{user | privacy: unquote(value)}
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule B do
  use A
end
```

```
iex(1)> %User{} |> B.make_public
%User{privacy: "public"}
```

---

Edit: Change requested in comments:

```
defmacro __using__(_) do
  Enum.map ~w(public private), fn value ->
    quote do
      def unquote(:"make_#{value}")(user = %User{}) do
        %{user | privacy: unquote(value)}
      end
      def unquote(:"make_#{String.upcase(value)}")(user = %User{}) do
        %{user | privacy: unquote(String.upcase(value))}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
iex(1)> %User{} |> B.make_public
%User{privacy: "public"}
iex(2)> %User{} |> B.make_PUBLIC
%User{privacy: "PUBLIC"}
iex(3)> %User{} |> B.make_private
%User{privacy: "private"}
iex(4)> %User{} |> B.make_PRIVATE
%User{privacy: "PRIVATE"}
```

Comment: But what if I need to add more functions to the same level as dynamically generated `def`?

Comment: You can put any number of `def` inside the `quote`.

Comment: The issue is that `__using__` functions expects an AST list of definitions, so if I declare multiple `quote` then only the last one is taken.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Does my edited answer do what you want?

Comment: @Dogbert A quick question: using `Enum.map` the returned value is a list of quoted function definition. This is inserted into the calling module. Does it define functions? Quoted list is the list itself, but does it mean that compiler executes each element, so functions are defined?

Comment: Yes, Elixir inserts each item of the list if you return a list (essentially merging all the quoted ASTs in the list) which is why this works.